# Client Rendering Problem after 'page.' calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, cross-posting

I have tried, 'PreviousPage', 'PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack' 'Page.previousPage', page.title

It causes the client to stop rendering the page after this line.

simple example

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
response.write("I can see this");
string test = PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack.toString(); //Any page call Causes client rendering to freeze
response.write("But i cant see this");   
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("However i can see this,proving that the server is still running the code");   
}
```

Anybody Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER

Well it ended up it was something stupid. code smell over.

The button i was using to fire the PostBack had a handler that fired to redirect, i just deleted the handler, keeping the PostBackUrl setting and magic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked PreviousPage for null?

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx):

> The PreviousPage property is a null
>   reference (Nothing in Visual Basic)
>   when the user requests that page
>   directly from the server.

Also - `MessageBox` in a web form, *not* a great idea... perhaps use the inbuilt [trace.axd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx)